# How to initialize google-cloud-firestore - Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

# Add a new document
db = firestore.Client()  # need to put credentials
doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace')
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Ada',
    u'last': u'Lovelace',
    u'born': 1815
})

# Then query for documents
users_ref = db.collection(u'users')

for doc in users_ref.stream():
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

This is a example code from https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/
When I run that it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kulothungan/Purp/temp/temp.py", line 4, in <module>
    db = firestore.Client()
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/client.py", line 94, in __init__
    client_options=client_options,
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_client.py", line 128, in __init__
    _http=None,
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 277, in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 225, in __init__
    project = self._determine_default(project)
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 244, in _determine_default
    return _determine_default_project(project)
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 186, in _determine_default_project
    _, project = google.auth.default()
  File "/home/kulothungan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 483, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

but I don't know how to initialize that and also I don't want to do that by using environmental variables
If anyone knows pls inform me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to this particular project, you need to go to the Google cloud console Service Accounts page [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) and create a service account for accessing firestore. [Service account creation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts). Give the service account one of the datastore [roles](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#roles) as appopriate.

Once created, you will have to generate keys for the service account. You can do this from the "Keys" tab on the service account's page.

[image: Service Account Key Creation]

Select the JSON format. You'll get a file called `keys.json`. Store that on your computer and create the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/keys.json
```

Now try running your python script.

## Without using Environment Variables

You need to install the `google-auth` python package which provides the `google.oauth2.service_account` module in which there is the `Credentials` class. You can initialize this class with your credentials like this:

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/keys.json')
```

Then you can pass this `credentials` object to the firestore `Client()` like this:

```py
db = firestore.Client(credentials=credentials)
```